# Remove multiple keys with same value data from dictionary in C# using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I know there has to be a better way to do this... maybe with LINQ? If I remove a value, it invalidates the iterator which is why I have this inside of an infinite loop which starts the process all over again. I'm looking for a way to do this that is easier to read, maintain and ultimately much faster. Here's what I got:

```
Dictionary<string, string> Channels = //...;
while (true)
{
    var bFound = false;
    foreach(var c in Channels)
    {
        if(c.Value == version)
        {
            Channels.Remove(c.Key);
            bFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!bFound) { break; }
}
```

Thanks for any help in optimizing this routine.

Comment: what does your dictionary look like?

Comment: @PatrickArtner -- updated question with more context

Comment: Why is this in an infinite loop?  "invalidates the iterator" does not makes sense.

Comment: once i call `Channels.Remove()`, the `foreach` throws an exception

Comment: @Andy well yeah, but why are you removing in the loop?  Just gather the keys you need in the loop and remove after.  Why does an infinite loop solve your problem (seems to just make it more confusing)

Comment: the infinite loop restarts the `foreach` from scratch -- brand new iterator. Take it out and just run it as is.. it will crash.

Comment: I don't understand why you have a loop. A dictionary's keys _must_ be unique. It seems to me like you should just call `Channels.Remove(version)` once and be done with it...

Comment: there are multiple values that match -- let's say it has 1000 keys, and 500 of those keys have the same value. I want to remove all 500 in one routine.

Comment: @charliefox2 OP is checking the _value_, it is spelled out multiple times in the post.  Look at the code, look at the title

Comment: All the answers below are omitting the important remark in the OP post _I'm looking for a way to do this that is easier to read, maintain and ultimately much faster._

Just use a `for` loop :)

Comment: @maccettura I'm smart I swear... oops. Sorry OP.

Comment: Yes-- checking value, not key. I understand that keys are unique.. but each key can have the same value all the way down. I want to remove keys that share a certain value... not key.

Comment: You want to remove ALL 500?  or 499 and keep one entry with the given value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your example it appears you are removing based on comparison with version value.

```
Channels = Channels.Where(x=> x.Value != version)
              .ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

Answer (score 3):

> I'm looking for a way to do this that is easier to read, maintain and ultimately much faster

Just use the code below:

```
var keys = Channels.Keys.ToArray();
foreach(var key in keys)
{
    if(Channels[key] == version)
    {
        Channels.Remove(key);
    }
}
```

No LINQ needed for simplicity. We traverse the dictionary once for performance.

Comment: there is a small error. It needs to be `if(Channels[key]== version)`

Comment: Did you try it?  The documentation for Keys indicates that changes to the underlying collection will be reflected, which may indicate that the enumerator will be invalidated.

Comment: @Andy I fixed my answer :).

Comment: @AmyB I'm not iterating on Channels collection but on variable keys which is not modified.

Comment: > The returned Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection is not a static copy; instead, the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection refers back to the keys in the original Dictionary<TKey, TValue>. Therefore, changes to the Dictionary<TKey, TValue> continue to be reflected in the Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.KeyCollection.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Should be fixable by setting `var keys = new List(Channels.Keys);`

Comment: @AmyB You're right dude :) FIxed it with `ToArray()`. Thanks :)

Comment: Good fix, I tried the old code and got System.InvalidOperationException : Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 2):

If you capture the matches before removing items from the dictionary, your enumerator will not be invalidated.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> matches = Channels
  .Where(kvp => kvp.Value == version)
  .ToList();

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> match in matches)
{
  Channels.Remove(match.Key);
}
```

Comment: Wouldnt it be better to avoid the call to `ToList();` ?

Comment: Suppose the ToList call is removed, then matches is now a deferred query with a source of Channels.  Once Channels is modified the deferred query will be unable to produce its next element.